# Exiftool: reorder images - copy them to folders based on their DateTimeOriginal

Tags: exiftool

I'm on Windows. The folder-structure of my photos looks like this:

```
D:
--source
    --yyyy
       --yyyymmdd
```

Example:

D:\source\2020\20201030\filename.ext

Currently the foldername 'yyyymmdd' seems to match the timestamp of the file, not its creation-timestamp. It seems that the transfer-routine, that copied the files from the SD-card to HDD did not always use the EXIF-creation-timestamp but the transfer-date to write the file-timestamp. This moved some pictures, shot at the end of a month, to the next month, but not always.

I still have to keep this original structure for a while, because some of my picture-libraries point on these files, so just moving them is no option. The libraries will be fixed in a second step.

I want to bring the files to an order, based on the EXIF-creation-timestamp of the files. The new folder-structure should reside on an usb-drive with the drive-letter 'P'.

To achieve this I want to copy all the files under 'D:\source' to 'P:\source_2':

```
P:
--source_2
    --yyyy
       --yyyymmdd
```

where 'yyyymmdd' should be taken from EXIF:DateTimeOriginal.

I had a look at several websites with EXIFTOOLS-command-examples, but I cannot figure out the correct command options.

Thank you for your time.

Peace

Comment: Exiftool has very powerful batch abilities and almost never needs to be run in a script.  Its startup time is its biggest performance hit and using it in a loop, calling it once for each file, can increase the processing time substantially.  See [exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

`exiftool -r -o . -d "%Y/%Y%m%d" "-Directory<P:/source_2/$DateTimeOriginal" D:/source`

Breakdown:
`-r` : [`-r` (`-recurse`) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse).  This will read through subdirectories looking for files to process.

`-o .` : [`-o` (`-out`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#o-OUTFILE-or-FMT--out).  This is used to copy the files to the new directory.  In this case, the dot is a dummy argument.  The `Directory` tag overrides it. See second paragraph under [Writing "FileName" and "Directory" tags -> Notes](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#Notes).

`-d` : [`-d` (`-dateFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#d-FMT--dateFormat).  This reformats the value of the `DateTimeOriginal` tag to match the desired directory structure. See [Common Date Format Codes](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#codes) if you want to change the format of the dates.

`"-Directory<P:/source_2/$DateTimeOriginal"` : This is the part where the files will be copied.  Under normal circumstances, writing to `Directory` will move the file, not copy, but this is overridden by the `-o` option. `P:/source_2/` is your target directory and the `DateTimeOriginal` will be reformatted as given in the `-d` option.  For example, a file with a `DateTimeOriginal` of `2023:02:28 12:00:00` will be listed as `2023/20230228`, with the end result of `P:/source_2/2023/20230228` as the target directory.

The above command assumes the use of Windows CMD.  In PowerShell (and on Mac/Linux), you would change the double quotes into single quotes, otherwise the dollar sign will be treated as the start of a shell variable.

Because exiftool is a Perl program, slashes `/` and backslashes `\` can be both be used as part of directory paths on Windows.  They will internally be converted to slashes.

This command does not take into account a case of two files with the same name.  In such a case, you would instead write to `Filename` and include some other exiftool `%` variables to format the filename, with `%-c` meaning that a (dash)(Number) will be added to any duplicate filenames :
`"-Filename<P:/source_2/$DateTimeOriginal/%f%-c.%e"`

If this command is used in a Windows BAT file, then all percent signs must be doubled.  See [exiftool FAQ #27](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q27).

Exiftool's startup time is its biggest performance hit and using it in a loop, calling it once for each file, can increase the processing time substantially.  Exiftool has very powerful batch abilities, so running it in a loop is almost never needed. See [exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).

Comment: Man, thank you so much. What a simple command, but it does the job perfectly. Saved me hours of time. Thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

After the installation of wsl with powershell command

```
wsl --install
```

you can run this script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Directory where the photos are located
photos_dir="/mnt/d/source"

# Directory where the photos should be moved to
move_dir="/mnt/p/source_2"

# Loop through all the .jpg files in the directory and its subdirectories
find "${photos_dir}" -type f -name '*.jpg' | while read photo; do

    # Use exiftool to read the date of the photo
    photo_date=$(exiftool -s -s -s -DateTimeOriginal "${photo}")

    # Check if the DateTimeOriginal field is present
    if [ -z "${photo_date}" ]; then
        echo "Warning: ${photo} does not have a DateTimeOriginal field, skipping..."
        continue
    fi

    # Extract the year, month, and day from the date
    year=$(echo "${photo_date}" | cut -d':' -f1)
    month=$(echo "${photo_date}" | cut -d':' -f2)
    day=$(echo "${photo_date}" | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -d' ' -f1)

    # Create the year folder if it doesn't already exist
    if [ ! -d "${move_dir}/${year}" ]; then
        mkdir "${move_dir}/${year}"
    fi

    # Create the folder if it doesn't already exist
    if [ ! -d "${move_dir}/${year}/${year}${month}${day}" ]; then
        mkdir "${move_dir}/${year}/${year}${month}${day}"
    fi

    # Move the photo to the folder
    mv "${photo}" "${move_dir}/${year}/${year}${month}${day}/"

done
```